# How to disable PLT Package

Tags: package

When I open a file with extension .plt, emacs behaves in a strange way. For example, I cannot type a space. I believe it has to do with something called the "PLT Package" because that name is displayed at the bottom of my window. However, no such package is listed in my .emacs file or in the list of packages accessible through emacs' menus.

I would simply like to remove/disable this package.

PS: In response to the suggestions so far, here is a screenshot that seems to indicate that "PLT Package" is related to a major mode.

[image]

Comment: Gnuplot files are often named .plt.

Comment: what version of emacs and where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has no special behaviour for the `.plt` file extension by default, so you have most likely added this library in your own config.

Assuming it is a major mode, I suggest using <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(find-function major-mode)` <kbd>RET</kbd> in the buffer to locate the library which defines it, which you could then delete (along with any other custom config you have relating to that library).

Make sure you delete the byte-compiled `.elc` file too, if one exists.

Comment: Thanks. Doing what you suggest takes me to the file lisp-mode.el.gz. Is that not a standard component of emacs?

Comment: It sure is.  "PLT Package" clearly *isn't* the major mode in that buffer (that was a guess on my part, as it wasn't obvious from your question), so most likely it is a minor mode.  Type `C-h m` in the buffer and look for something related in the list of minor modes at the top.  The following *might* tell you:  `M-: (car (cl-member " PLT Package" minor-mode-alist :key 'cadr :test 'equal))`

Comment: That said, it's curious to me that your `.plt` buffer must have been in `lisp-mode` (being the only major mode defined in `lisp-mode.el`).  That may give you further information.  Perhaps just use `C-h v auto-mode-alist` and search with `C-s` for `plt` -- if your config is picking up on the file extension, it should be configured in there.

Comment: Thanks! C-h m brings out "PLT Package mode defined in `quack.el': nil".
C-h v auto-mode-alist gives " ("\\.plt\\'" . quack-pltfile-mode)". So how do I disable quack?

Comment: just delete `quack.el` and `quack.elc` and remove the config the way phils described (Are you using Debian? In which case, quack comes along with many other useful tools, in emacs-goodies-el https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs-goodies-el . The config is probably in /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50emacs-goodies-el.el )